# HighCharts set different xAxis labels

Tags: highcharts

I am using 2 arrays with some numbers and getting the percentage. What I would like to do is if both array indexes are 0 the I would like to set the Label to read "No Data".

I know I need to get the current column(point) index or something similar, I've tried using formatters to do this.

Anyways I imagine the code something like this.

```
xAxis: {
   categories: trebleNotes,
       labels: {
               rotation: -45,
               align: 'right',
               style: {
                  fontSize: '13px',
                  fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
               },
               formatter: function () {
                 if(array1[currentColumn] == 0 && array2[currentColumn] == 0){
                        return("NO DATA");
                      }else{
                         return(this.value);
                      }
               },
             }
       },
```

I am not sure how to get the currentColumn index and use that to do the formatting. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, wouldn't you just want the index of the category at `this.value`?

```
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                var currentColumn = -1;
                for (var idx = 0; idx < this.axis.categories.length; idx++){
                    if (this.axis.categories[idx] == this.value){
                        currentColumn = idx;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                console.log(currentColumn);
                return this.value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. That almost seems like it would work, it allows me to get the columns index.. but the categories are the same in alot of the instances (have the same value repeated) so I am getting the "currentColumn" repeated several times.

Comment: Do you have any live demo of your chart?